# How can I main use other codes?

Tags: java, overriding

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Character {
    public String name;
    public int hp;
    public int atk;
}//public class Character

class Wizard extends Character {
    public void main(){
        name = "Wizard";
        hp = 15;
        atk = 5;
    }
}//public class hero extends character

class Warrior extends Character {
    public void main(){
        name = "Warrior";
        hp = 20;
        atk = 3;
    }
}//public class hero extends character

class Monster extends Character {
    public void main() {
        name = "Monster";
        hp = 5;
        atk = 1;
    }
}//class Monster extends Character


public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int hero;
            hero = sc.nextInt();

            if(hero==1)
            {
                human = new Warrior();

            } else if(hero==2){

                human = new Wizard();}
}
```

In this case, java main cannot find Warrior and Wizard and monsters.
i know theres only can just one override.
but i want main code can load warrior, wizard, and monsters.
how can I fix it? is it possable? 
thanks for your help.

Comment: how can i change instance to others? in Character, i tryed give main but than Warrior and Monster cannot find symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define human. Probably as "Character" in your case. After change that you can run your code.

```
...
public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int hero;
            hero = sc.nextInt();

            Character human; //add this line

            if(hero==1)
            {
                human = new Warrior();

            } else if(hero==2){

                human = new Wizard();}
}
```